# else statements won't execute in an if else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

For some reason, no matter what I do, every time I make an if else statement in my Java programs, it either only ever executes the if statement, or both the if and else statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Week06_NelsonPimentel_Assignment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] validnum;
        int i = 0;
        validnum = new int[5];

        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 50 and 100");

        while (i < validnum.length) {
            validnum[i] = input.nextInt();

            if (validnum[i] <= 101 || validnum[i] >= 49) {
                System.out.println("yes");
                i++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("no");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: If it seems like a strange process that is because this a smaller part of a bigger program, but for now the if else statements simply will not work correctly

Comment: `validnum[i] <= 101 || validnum[i] >= 49` is always true

Comment: You mean `&&`, not `||`. But note that your logic doesn't match your message.

Comment: [take a look](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if (validnum[i] <= 101 || validnum[i] >= 49) {` will always evaluate to `true`, and so "yes" will be printed and `i` incremented, unless of course `i` is outside the bounds of the array.

Replace `||` with `&&`?

Also consider writing `int[] validnum = new int[5];` rather than having two separate steps. That way, `validnum` is never in an uninitialised state which tends to result in stabler programs.

Comment: "That way, validnum is never in an uninitialised state" Definite assignment?

Comment: it did not work, at first, but now it's actually working quite well, thank you everybody for the quick responses cause this has been tearing me apart for literally 3 hours!!

Comment: @AndyTurner: It's tricky (or at least I find it tricky) to use terms that a beginner will understand. You have a better idea?

Comment: @Bathsheba I just wouldn't have called it out as a reason. Sure, do it because it's more concise and idiomatic, it's just not safer. (Also mention it if it had been initialized to `null`).

Comment: Perhaps I'm simply a dinosaur languishing in the cretaceous world of C and C++.

Comment: @zenon: It's quite a common mistake since && and || can be construed to be at odds with written English. Do make sure you follow the logic behind the change,.

Answer (score 0):

You have an **endless loop** in your code, when `validnum[i]` doesn't meet your condition you don't advance your loop index. 
Take `i++;` out of the `if` or replace your `while` loops with (**NOTE:** You don't neet `i++;` if you are using `for` loop):

```
for (int i = 0; i < validnum.length; i++) {
        validnum[i] = input.nextInt();

        if (validnum[i] <= 101 || validnum[i] >= 49) {
            System.out.println("yes");
        } else {
            System.out.println("no");
        }
}
```

Why do you use the array? in the code you posted it looks like a waste of memory.

Answer (score 0):

As per your business logic the if statement will always returns true.

My Observation:
Please enter a number between 50 and 100.

```
validnum[i] = input.nextInt();
if (validnum[i] <= 101 || validnum[i] >= 49) {
}
```

Whether you are enter between 50 to 100 or less than 50 or greater than 100 the if statement will always satisfied either one of the below condition

```
validnum[i] <= 101 
validnum[i] >= 49
```